# Compile annotation processor-generated files in its own test project with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I have a Gradle project in which I define an annotation processor. When using the processor in other projects down the line, this works fine.

However, I want to unit test the processor, so I have some test code that uses the processor. The processor runs fine on the test code without me having to configure anything, but unlike in other projects, the generated code is not compiled.

For clarification, this is what my project looks like (after calling `gradle clean test`):

```
src
|- main
  |- java
    |- my.package.Processor
  |- resources
    |- META-INF/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
|- test
  |- java
    |- my.package.ClassWithAnnotationToBeProcessed.java
    |- my.package.TheUnitTest.java
build
|- main
|- test
  |- my.package.GeneratedFile.java // missing .class file!
build.gradle
```

Comment: Can you post the build.gradle files? Am having a similar problem

Comment: No, I decided to go with a solution without processor in the end.